# How can I mount a remote volume with 777 permissions for all users?

Tags: ubuntu, php, permissions, mount, terminal

I want users to be able to upload files to a central file server via my PHP script. I mounted the file server's shared volume using this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.8/share local_dir -o username=user,password=pass
```

Whilst I could `sudo chmod` my way to write access, there are hundreds of directories which already exist:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2011-03-30 15:59 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2011-04-04 16:27 dir2
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2011-04-04 18:07 dir3
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2011-04-06 13:41 dir4
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2011-04-06 13:39 dir5
....etc
```

I may need to create a new directory or move the uploaded file to an existing directory.

Is there anything I can do to make this share writeable by any user? The only other solution I can think of is to have Apache run as root. I won't be doing *that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.8/share local_dir -o username=user,password=pass,umask=0777

Comment: Thanks Jason, your answer pointed me in the direction of the solution. You probably would have given me the correct solution if I'd mentioned that the remote share is a **Windows volume**.

Answer (score 1):

An answer for **2022** - the `umask` parameter now seems to be `file_mode` - that got it working for me.

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/427044/mounting-cifs-drive-gives-mount-error22-invalid-argument for that one.